# Rapid Json Writer Exception

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am using Rapidjson C++ Library. When I write Json array, In some cases I might write in a wrong order. 
For Ex., see the below case.

```
Writer.StartObject();
   Writer.StartArray();
     Writer.String("red");
     Writer.String("Blue");
   Writer.EndArray();
Writer.EndObject();
```

The above code is correct. But In some cases, If I write the code in a wrong order like as below.

```
Writer.StartObject();
 Writer.StartObject();
   Writer.StartArray();
     Writer.String("red");
     Writer.String("Blue");
   Writer.EndArray();
Writer.EndObject();
```

I know the code is wrong. It should have two consecutive Plain Object. It is an RunTime Error. But I should handle the exception at runtime. I studied RapidJson Library Document. But I couldn't find How to handle this runtime exception in RapidJson Library. Is there anyway to Handle the exception in Rapidjson? Or do any other library available to handle the above Exception?

Comment: It seems, RapidJson doesn't allow this way. As a dirty soluton for this you can try to modify RAPIDJSON_ASSERT macro to throw exceptions...